# How can I connect to an external and embedded database via Spring @Profile?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, h2

Basically, the problem is that I can't connect to the internal database via a file

I have two entities

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "id_news")
    private long id_news;

}

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class News {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;
   @Column(name = "date")
   private Date date;
   @Column(name = "title")
   private String title;
   @Column(name = "text")
   private String text;
   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, targetEntity = Comment.class)
   private List<Comment> comments;

}
```

Based on them, I created data.sql (I'm not sure if this is correct)

```
CREATE TABLE news
(
    id    bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    date  timestamp without time zone,
    text  character varying(255),
    title character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT news_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE comment
(
    id       bigint NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    date     timestamp without time zone,
    id_news  bigint,
    text     character varying(255),
    username character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT comment_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO news (title, date, text)
VALUES
('News 2', '2020-05-11', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin vestibulum quis tellus vitae cursus. In ut felis posuere quam varius.'),
('News 4', '2019-05-05', 'Nulla diam lectus, scelerisque vitae scelerisque et, ultrices vitae ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.');
```

I tried to connect the database with this class

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class ConfigH2Db {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .addScript("data.sql")
                .build();
        return db;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

}
```

I connected PostgreSQL in this way through the application.properties file and everything worked well

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters=true
```

Comment: can you provide details of the error you are seeing?

Comment: The application itself starts, but the internal database is not filled, the main thing for me now is to create a database through "data.sql" with tables and data